# Ubuntu 18.04 randomly freezes indefinitely

Tags: 18.04, drivers, intel-graphics, freeze

I switched my os from windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04 because some drivers were unsupported and i switched. Since ive had Ubuntu every now and then my laptop freezes and doesnt unfreeze so i have to do force shutdown. Now it almost freezes everyday. It might also be becuase i have two different 4gb ram sticks.

```
Specs:
-Computer- Dell Latitude E4310
Processor       : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 540  @ 2.53GHz
Memory      : 8076MB (4926MB used)
Machine Type        : Laptop
Operating System        : Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
-Display-
Resolution      : 1366x768 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics (ILK)
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
-Audio Devices-
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
-Input Devices-
 Lid Switch
 Power Button
 Sleep Button
 Power Button
 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
 AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick
 AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad
 Video Bus
 Dell WMI hotkeys
 Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2M: In
 HDA Intel Dock Mic
 HDA Intel Mic
 HDA Intel Dock Line Out
 HDA Intel Headphone
-Printers-
No printers found
-SCSI Disks-
ATA ST9250414ASG
TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-U633J
```

If you would like more info please inform me on how to obtain it cause i am relatively new :).

Comment: Hi! I have a similar problem with the screen freezing, I can move my mouse though. Can you try CTRL+ALT+F1 to get back to login screen? If that works, maybe we have a similar problem. Also, in Linux / Ubuntu distros a good start when the system freezes entirely is holding ALT+PrtSc (Print Screen or SysRq) key while typing R E I S U B slowly. that will reboot the system more safely in the end. (what it does is described here for instance: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/6qphtj/psa_use_reisub_when_ubuntu_stops_responding/ )

Comment: I am not even able to move my mouse cursor, even the time it stops the seconds dont update and so ctrl+alt+f1 is impossible. As for second method it doesnt even work, it might be because of the layout of the keyboard because i have to use Fn keys with the f row for SysRQ and Prnt Scrn while holding alt.